# How To call UseEffect before render in functional component of react native

Tags: react-native

I Want to create dynamic Bottom Navigation , In which I want to change one of bottom navigator depends upon user type.
My code

```
const createBottomTabs = () => {
 const [userType, SetuserType] = useState('aa');
   useEffect(() => {
     _retrieveData = async () => {
        const user_type = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_type');
        SetuserType(user_type)         
      }
      _retrieveData()
   }, []);
  
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name={userType} // that should be dynamic
          component={Component}
          ....
```

It give me 'aa' but I want Updated State value. Any Help ?

Comment: `useEffect` runs after the component mounts, which is after the first render.

Comment: then what should I do in that case?

Comment: @alex you can set a loading indicator instead of "aa" while your data comes back

Answer (score 0):

**useLayoutEffect** that has the same signature like useEffect can fire before view rendering.

But I dont think you can dynamically change a route name like that. Here is a better way :

```
<Tab.Screen
  name={"TabName"}
  component={component}
  options={{
   tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
    if(!userType) 
      return (
       <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", height: 58 }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size={"small"} color="blue" />
       </View>
      )
    return (
      <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", height: 58 }}>
         <Icon name="..." type="..." color={focused ? "blue" : "#9E9E9E"}/>
         <Text style={{color={focused ? "blue" : "#9E9E9E"}}}>{userType}</Text>
      </View>
    );
   },
  }}
/>
```